# How do I return a Base64 encoded zip file through AWS api-gateway for download

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I built a python lambda which generates a zip file containing a certificate and password. The file is base64 encoded and returned using proxy integration through the API gateway. Hitting the API gateway with a the browser prompts to download. The response is saved to a file with a zip extension.

The saved file is still base64 encoded. The end users should receive a working zip file. Base64 decoding the file gives a valid zip file. The user should not have to decode the file.

Adding a `Content-Encoding` header causes the API gateway integration to fail with the error that it cannot base64 decode the response from the lambda.

Note - Stripping the leading and trailing characters from the b64content fixes the `str()` function putting a leading `b'` and trailing tic. Can you tell I'm a noob to python and AWS? ;-)

```
                headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/zip,  application/octet-stream',
                           'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{filename}.zip"'
                           }
                if 'b64' in event['params']:
                    headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'base64'

                response = {
                    'statusCode': 200,
                    'isBase64Encoded': True,
                    'headers': headers,
                    'body': str(b64content)[2:-1],
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was due to 2 different issues.

First, the AWS sample code is Python2. The lambda is Python3. The encoding for strings and bytes has changed in Python3 so the base64 byte array needed `.decode('utf-8')` before returning it. (The encoding is not required but [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))

Second, the API gateway was not properly treating the returned data as base64 encoded. Adding the `content-encoding: base64` header caused the API to decode the base64 data before returning it to the client.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407298/why-am-i-getting-a-runtime-marshalerror-when-using-this-code-in-zapier) about a runtime marshaling error got me half of the answer.